# Nrwl/React - Upload source maps to sentry

Tags: reactjs, sentry, source-maps, nrwl-nx

I'm working on a React application inside my NX Workspace.

Now I want to add sentry to my project. I already have a deploy configuration in my `project.json`. But I'm struggling with adding the step to upload the source maps.

Here is my `project.json`

```
"deploy": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "parallel": false,
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "nx run my-app:build:{args.target}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          },
          {
            "command": "echo Run {args.target} deployment on {args.server}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          },
          {
            "command": "rsync -avz --progress --delete dist/apps/my-app/ {args.user}@{args.server}:{args.path}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          },
          {
            "command": "echo my-app deployed to {args.target}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "args": "--target=production --user=user --server=myserver.com --path=path/to/app"
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there any example of how to perform the upload of the source maps using a nx workspace? Or do I have to create a custom script that handles everything and put it into my `project.json` as the second command (after build, before deploy).

Also, I'm not sure how to handle the version number of my application as NX does not provide a way to define version numbers for each application inside the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom webpack config on the Nx project: https://nx.dev/recipes/other/customize-webpack

and then follow the instructions on how to setup it on Sentry using webpack:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/sourcemaps/uploading/webpack/

Your custom webpack should look like something like this:

```
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge')
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin')
const nrwlConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js')

module.exports = (config) => {
  // merge config from @nrwl/react first
  nrwlConfig(config)

  return merge(config, {
    devtool: 'source-map', // Source map generation must be turned on
    plugins: [
      new SentryWebpackPlugin({
        org: 'orgId',
        project: 'projectId',
        // Specify the directory containing build artifacts
        include: './build',
        // Auth tokens can be obtained from https://sentry.io/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/
        // and needs the `project:releases` and `org:read` scopes
        authToken: process.env.NX_SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
        // Optionally uncomment the line below to override automatic release name detection
        // release: process.env.RELEASE,
      }),
    ],
  })
}
```

Please notice that unfortunately this is not a final answer, because with this I can upload the artifact, but the source maps are still not working on Sentry and I don't know why yet - but maybe this can be helpful somehow to you.